# Why does SQL Server Profiler crash when its run against a DB machine from a client machine?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, profiler

I have:

- `SQL Server 2014` (default instance )is on a `Win Server 2012` machine.
- `SQL Server Management Studio` (v17.7) is on a `Win 7` machine.
- Both machines are on the same domain.
- I'm logged into the `Win 7` machine as a domain admin.
- My domain admin account has SQL Server Security sysadmin
  access.

On the `Win 7` machine, I bring up `SSMS` and I connect OK to the DB that is on the Win Server 2012 machine. However, on `SSMS`, when I do `Tools -> SQL Server Profiler`, I get a dialog "Profile Application has stopped working". The event log shows the following which seems weird because I would expect `Profiler.exe` to be run on the remote `Win Server 2012` DB machine

Why does SQL Server Profiler crash when its run against a DB machine from a client machine?

```
Faulting application name: Profiler.exe, version: 2017.140.17254.0, time stamp: 0x5ae98b94
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x75bb48cb
Faulting process id: 0x4e0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d42da026f3a3d9
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\Profiler.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 652f0139-9993-11e8-9f5b-327e82b70454
```

Comment: Profiler would be run on the same machine as SSMS.  It does not launch a remote profiler.  You may need to reinstall things.

Comment: Profiler, really, shouldn't be used any more anyway. Ideally, instead, you should be using Extended Events. Profiler itself is actually deprecated, I *think* since 2012, however, is still shipped with the latest version of SSMS.